# Write SQLite DB from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sqlite

i have a following scenario that i have a products, categories and subcategories in mysql i want to create the SQLite DB so what i do first I create the XML and and then parse the xml and create Database its has problem i getting that i get too much error in xml because data are too complicated and special characters in the database so is it any possiblity to write direct SQLite DB or some SQL Script which runs in sqlite.. please tell me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently discovered a great ORM layer called RedBean - http://redbeanphp.com/
You can attach it to all kinds of RDMS, even Sqlite.

I suggest it because it can create table structures on-the-fly, without writing CREATE TABLE...

Comment: just checking but it could create the script or db what i want